# Make New-PSDrive drive viewable to another device when a USB cable is plugged into each device

Tags: powershell

I need to map a drive as a virtual USB so that when a male to male USB cord is plugged into both devices the folder that is now a mapped drive can be seen by the other device plugged into the other end of the USB cord.

Mapping the folder is easy enough. When this is run it maps a drive (K) that has the content in the folder "Folder1",
but how do I make this viewable by "Computer B" when the USB cable is plugged into both computers?
The second device is a Linux based computer

<***$Path = "\\Computer_A\Folder1"***>

<***New-PSDrive –Name “K” –PSProvider FileSystem –Root $Path –Persist?***>

Answer (score 0):

This reminds me that MicroSoft removed Easy Transfer from Windows 10. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-easy-transfer-is-not-available-in-windows-10-ff30fba8-9b3e-58f8-5cf2-dfabae35fa01

This may not be possible the way you want.